# How to access the next key in a Swift dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsdictionary

I have this code

```
for (k, v) in myDict {
    println(k)
}
```

How do I access the next key in the dictionary (e.g. myDict[k + 1])?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Given that the order of the keys in a dictionary is undefined, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "the next key"; dictionaries have no order.

Since, however, you are iterating through the dictionary...

```
for (k, v) in myDict {
    println(k)
}
```

I'm going to assume that what you mean is: how can I know, on *this* iteration, what `k` would be on the *next* iteration?

A simple solution would be to coerce the dictionary to an array (of key-value tuples):

```
let arr = Array(myDict)
```

Now you have something with integer indexes. So you can enumerate it like this:

```
let arr = Array(myDict)
for (ix, (k,v)) in enumerate(arr) {
    println("This key is \(k)")
    if ix < arr.count-1 {
        println("The next key is \(arr[ix+1].0)")
    }
}
```

---

The truth is, of course, that you *can* enumerate a dictionary directly, but indexes are not integers, so they are a little harder to work with. Martin R is also showing an approach illustrating that point.

Comment: Thanks @matt! That worked, you were correct, apologies for not being more specified. I did indeed want to know on this iteration, what k would be on the next iteration

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but you can
iterate through a dictionary in a "similar" way as iterating
through an array by using the `DictionaryIndex<Key, Value>` as an index:

```
let dict = [ "foo" : 1, "bar" : 2, "baz" : 3]

for idx in indices(dict) {

    let (k, v) = dict[idx]
    println("Current key: \(k), current value: \(v)")

    let nextIdx = idx.successor()
    if nextIdx != dict.endIndex {
        let (k1, v1) = dict[nextIdx]
        println("Next key: \(k1), next value: \(v1)")
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Current key: bar, current value: 2
Next key: baz, next value: 3
Current key: baz, current value: 3
Next key: foo, next value: 1
Current key: foo, current value: 1
```

Comment: `advance(idx, 1)` or: `idx.successor()`

Comment: `for var idx = dict.startIndex ; idx != dict.endIndex ; idx++` or: `for idx in dict.startIndex..<dict.endIndex`

Comment: also I find `indices(dict)` nicer than `dict.startIndex..<dict.endIndex`

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity: Indeed, I had forgotten about that. (Is this still my answer ?)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to create `Generator` which returns the current and previous values in a sequence. For this you need a custom `Generator` which will return a tuple, containing the previous and current values from a sequence, from `next`:

```
struct PairGenerator<Base: GeneratorType> : GeneratorType {
    typealias ElementPair = (previousElement: Base.Element, currentElement: Base.Element)

    private var base: Base
    private var previousElement: Base.Element?

    init(_ base: Base) {
        self.base = base
    }

    mutating func next() -> ElementPair? {
        if previousElement == nil { previousElement = base.next() }
        let currentElement = base.next()

        // Since `base.next()` returns `nil` when the end of the sequence
        // is reached, we need to check `previousElement` and `currentElement ` 
        // aren't `nil`. If either of them are, `nil` will be returned to signal
        // there aren't any pairs left.
        if let prev = previousElement, curr = currentElement {
            previousElement = currentElement
            return (prev, curr)
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

The `PairGenerator` is then stored in a `PairSequence`, which conforms to `SequenceType`; this means you can iterate over it in a `for` loop.

```
struct PairSequence<Base: SequenceType> : SequenceType {
    let generator: PairGenerator<Base.Generator>

    init(_ base: Base) {
        generator = PairGenerator(base.generate())
    }

    func generate() -> PairGenerator<Base.Generator> {
        return generator
    }
}
```

Now you need a function which will create a `PairSequence` from an object that conforms to `SequenceType`:

```
func pairs<Seq: SequenceType>(base: Seq) -> PairSequence<Seq> {
    return PairSequence(base)
}
```

Finally, you can use this like so:

```
let myDict = ["1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3, "4": 4]
let values = Array(myDict.values).sorted(<)

for (prev, curr) in pairs(values) {
    println("\(prev), \(curr)")
}

// Prints:
// 1, 2
// 2, 3
// 3, 4
```

You could use `pairs(myDict)`, but like @Martin R and @matt said - Dictionaries don't have an order so you may not get the results in the order you expected.

For more information on `SequenceType` and `GeneratorType`, I'd recommend looking at [Playing With Swift](https://schani.wordpress.com/2014/06/03/playing-with-swift/) and [Generators In Swift](https://schani.wordpress.com/2014/06/06/generators-in-swift/).

---

Or, as @Martin R pointed out in his comment, you could use:

```
for (prev, curr) in zip(values, dropFirst(values)) {
    println("\(prev), \(curr)")
}
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, `zip(values, dropFirst(values))` would give the same sequence as your `pairs(values)` .

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of that. That's definitely a lot simpler!