# How to replace array with elements in another array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an first array: `["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]`

and the second array: `["1", "0", "1", "1"]`.

Now I need to replace first array with elements from second array.
The result should be: `["1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0"]`

Comment: you want to replace or add first array after second array

Answer (score 7):

try:

```
var array1 = ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]
let array2 = ["1", "0", "1", "1"]

array1[0..<array2.count] = array2[0..<array2.count]
println(array1)
```

Comment: Or, according to [a recent suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464861/how-to-access-the-next-key-in-a-swift-dictionary/30465659#comment49013876_30465659): `array1[indices(array2)] = array2[indices(array2)]` .

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `enumerate` function to get the index while looping:

```
var arr1 = ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]
let arr2 = ["1", "0", "1", "1"]

for (index, value) in enumerate(arr2) {
    arr1[index] = value
}

arr1 // ["1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0"]
```

Comment: For Swift 3, replace `enumerate(arr2)` with `arr2.enumerated()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
var array1 = ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"];
var array2 = ["1", "0", "1", "1"];

array1.replaceRange(Range(start:0, end:array2.count), with: array2)

NSLog("\(array1)");
```

> [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
var arr2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
arr[0...arr2.count-1] = arr2[0...arr2.count-1]

println(arr)   // prints "[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]"
```

arr[i...j] gives you the range between i th and j th elements (inclusive) so you can change a specific portion of the array directly.